# How to set img tag src in MVC 4?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a file input control:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUploadControl" />
```

On selecting an image file using this file control the selected image `src` has to be updated in `img` tag:

```
<img id="profileImage" width="80%" height="80%" />
```

I used the folowing jQuery code to update the `src`:

```
$("#fileUploadControl").on('change', function(){
     $("#profileImage ").attr('src', 'url(file://' + $(this).val() + ')');
})
```

The above code works in ordinary HTML page but when I use this code inside the MVC 4 .cshtml file it didn't work.

What is the reason and how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: Did you check console for error?

Comment: @The-Val I checked using, IE8's Developer tools source code. It shows the img tag as  <img id="profileImage" style="width: 80%; height: 80%;" src="file:///C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"/>
But I could not see the updated image.

Comment: it seems that you are having an issue with path. see that its clearly wrong

Comment: I copied the image tag in a html file.
<img id="profileImage" style="width: 80%; height: 80%;" src="file:///C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Koala.jpg"/>
It is working in IE and FF.But in MVC 4 .cshtml file it is not working

Comment: where did you bind this event in mvc project? and you can be more specific about selectors while binding events like '$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#element').on("click", "img", function (event) {
            $("#profileImage ").attr('src', 'url(file://' + $(this).val() + ')');        });
    });'

Answer (score 0):

I have done this in one of my asp.net project,may this helps you

FileUpload control

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="screenUpload" runat="server" onchange="readURL(this);"/>
```

Image control

```
<img width="100" id="imgProjImage" runat="server" src=""/>
```

Function

```
function readURL(input) {
            if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
                var reader = new FileReader();

                reader.onload = function(e) {
                    $('#imgProjImage').attr('src', e.target.result);
                }

                reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Surely this is not an option in Mvc?

Comment: Its working fine for me on any browser for test you can try this.

Comment: It doesnt work in ie8. IE8 doesnt support fileReader.I works fine in FF.